# How do you match against the type "Either a b"?

Tags: haskell, types

The purpose for this particular portion of code is to make the `size` function more efficient than simply counting all the elements in `elems`.  I've settled on summing the two types that make up the list, but I can't seem to create the signature of the size function.

```
instance (Finite a, Finite b) => Finite (Either a b) where
    elems = combineLists [Left x | x <- elems] [Right x | x <-elems]
    size ??? = (size a) + (size b)
```

From Prelude, we know that `Either a b = Left a | Right b`.

The first thing I tried was to match `Either`, but of course it is a type, so that doesn't work.  Next, I tried `((Left a) | (Right b))`, but no go on that either. Nothing else seems to match the type `Either a b`.

I was able to get `size (Left a)` to compile, but since it's missing the `b` component, I receive the error:

```
Ambiguous type variable `b' in the constraint:
  `Finite b' arising from a use of `size' at <interactive>:1:0-12
```

which of course makes sense in the context, but I really have no clue how to match `Either a b`.

Anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: You seem a little confused about the difference between a type and a constructor.  "Either a b" is a type with two constructors, "Left" and "Right".  Types go in type signatures, while constructors go in code.  This is a common confusion because a lot of types use the same name for the type and the constructor, as in "data Foo = Foo Int String"; the first "Foo" is the type, while the second is the constructor.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something of type `Either a b` is either a `Left a` or a `Right b`, so you have two cases that can be handled separately:

```
size (Left x) = size x
size (Right x) = size x
```

The error about the ambiguous type variable is a separate issue.
If you just type something like `size (Left 1)` into the interpreter, the system can't deduce what the "right" type of that `Left 1` value would be. It could be `Either Int anything` and as long as it is not known what type that `anything` is, it cannot be checked if it is in class `Finite` (which is required by `size`).

You can avoid that problem by specifying an explicit type signature:

```
size (Left 1 :: Either Int String)
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble seems to be that you need a dummy argument for `size`, but you can't pass dummies for both types `a` and `b` in a single `Either a b`.  Perhaps you can use the `elems` to get a dummy of each type:

```
size _ = (size . head) (elems :: [a]) + (size . head) (elems :: [b])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the core issue you are having is that you want a type that represents a datum from each of two other types at the same time. `Either a b` can only be one of `a` or `b` at a give time.

A simple data type that represents both an `a` and a `b` at the same time is a 2-tuple. The type signature for such a thing is `(a, b)`, which is also the expression for creating one, and hence pattern maching one:

```
> :type (4,5)
(4,5) :: (Num t, Num t1) => (t, t1)
> let f (a, b) = 2*a + b
> f (4,5)
13
```

You should consider writing your first line with a 2-tuple, like so:

```
 instance (Finite a, Finite b) => Finite (a, b) where
```

What does this `Finite (a, b)` represent? What would the member function definitions be?

Comment: Actually I've already written the definition of that, it is the product of a and b, creating a mapping of all a's to all b's